# Why nested bind can defer evaluation of the expression

Tags: c++, c++11

Item 34 in [Effective modern C++] gives an example that nested bind can defer evaluation of `steady_clock::now()` until `setAlarm` is invoked.
`std::chrono::steady_clock::now` is actually a `static` member function. My understanding is that whenever it is passed as function argument, it will be evaluated.

Can anyone help to elaborate on why it can be deferred?

```
auto setSoundB =
    std::bind(setAlarm,
        std::bind(std::plus<>(), steady_clock::now(), 1h),
        _1,
        30s);
```

Comment: `auto setSoundB = [](auto&& p) { return setAlarm(steady_clock::now() + 1h, p, 30s); };` seems simpler, BTW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example that call to `steady_clock::now()` is not deferred.

To prevent `steady_clock::now()` from evaluating now, wrap that in another `bind` call:

```
std::bind(&steady_clock::now)
```

E.g.:

```
auto mynow() {
    std::cout << "mynow\n";
    return std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}

int main(int ac, char**) {
    std::cout << "creating a bind object\n";
    auto f = std::bind(std::plus<>(), mynow(), 1h);
    std::cout << "invoking bind object\n";
    f();


    std::cout << "\ncreating a bind object\n";
    auto g = std::bind(std::plus<>(), std::bind(&mynow), 1h);
    std::cout << "invoking bind object\n";
    g();
}
```

Outputs:

```
creating a bind object
mynow
invoking bind object

creating a bind object
invoking bind object
mynow
```

See [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) for details:

> **Member function operator()**
>
> If the stored argument `arg` is of type `T` for which `std::is_bind_expression<T>::value == true` (for example, another `bind` expression was passed directly into the initial call to `bind`), then `bind` performs function composition: instead of passing the function object that the `bind` subexpression would return, the subexpression is invoked eagerly, and its return value is passed to the outer invokable object...

Comment: Thanks. It should be an alternative way to defer evaluation by pass a pointer to function. But I still want to figure out why nested bind can help.

Comment: @Kane Added details for you.

Comment: Actually my example indeed defer the evaluation. You can see the output in  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b77eed7393a8da70.

Comment: @Kane No, it does not.

Comment: Looks you're right. Nested bind can't help, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a9073785792558a. Is it a known error in the book - effective modern c++?

Comment: @Kane [It is a known bug in the book](http://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/emc++-errata.html): _The revised versions of `setSoundB` still invoke `steady_clock::now()` when `std::bind` is called instead of when the bind object is called. **A proper fix requires nesting a third call to `std::bind` inside the second one.**_

Comment: Why in the world are people still using `std::bind`; I have seen something like 2 uses ever that C++14 lambdas don't solve better with fewer quirks.  This one included.  (And 99% of cases C++11 lambdas solve just fine).

Comment: @Yakk Could not agree more. Coincidentally, this code sample is from Effective Modern C++, chapter "Item 34: Prefer lambdas to std::bind".